# Azure Functional App 2.0 Sql Not Supported Error

Tags: function, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Server from function App 2.0 using .NET core.

After i have added the SQL Data client reference and run the app i am getting not supported error can you please help on this.

Comment: Can you please add your code? Are you using VS or portal?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error you are getting and the code that causes the error?

Comment: Can you please add a detailed error description and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import SQL version 4.4.0 to make it work latest nuget update is breaking the changes,